# Accessing controls in Razor view from controller MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor-2

I am new to MVC. In my application the view page created using razor by designing it from another html page designer. I have doubt that how to access the html controls from the corresponding controller. For example, i create a controller named Home and and corresponding view. Added a text box into it.

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="txtName"/>
```

Now i want to get and set the value in text box from controller without using script.
Just like

```
txtName.text="...."
```

Is that possible..?

Comment: somewhat...are you using a model with the view?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are thinking of things from a Web Forms perspective, e.g. controls, setting properties server-side.

MVC allows much better [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), that is, each piece should play its part without being tightly coupled to other parts. Having a controller set a property of a textbox in a view means that there must always be a textbox in that view and would tightly couple the controller to that particular view. It is not directly possible and it would be a bad idea even if it was.

That's where view models come in:

```
// M - model
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// V - view
@model MyViewModel

// (usually code to begin a form goes here)

@Html.TextBoxFor( o => o.Name )

// C - controller
public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel { Name = "Hello" };
    return View( model );
}
```

It may seem like an extra step (it is) but it is cleaner, far more flexible, and far more test-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

It would only be possible with another request to the server (e.g. POST, GET) because the Controller code can only run server-side. After processing another request, you could use a ViewModel to populate your HTML text-box while rendering it, but I doubt that is what you are looking for.

If you are familiar with desktop programming (e.g. Window's Forms) and you are looking to immediately change and process  fields on an HTML page, you will need to use JavaScript. If you are unfamiliar with web-programming, or even just new to the MVC paradigm, I suggest you try out a few [MSDN tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4).